# How do I add an event listener to a component that is instantiated multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener

I am building a `<Tooltip>` component and I would like to close the tooltip when the `esc` key is clicked. I add and remove the `keydown` event listener in a `useEffect()`:

```
const removeTooltip = (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Escape') {
    // remove tooltip
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', removeTooltip);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', removeTooltip);
  };
}, []);
```

The event listener works as expected, but if I instantiate multiple tooltips on the same page, the event is added for each one. Is there a way to check if `window` is already listening for the event? What is the best way to add the event listener once?

Comment: Aren't you using a reference to the rendered tooltip in `removeTooltip`, so that each distinct handler is necessary? How are you removing the tooltip?

Comment: I would just add it once on app load and then have an array of tooltip references available.  Whenver the ESC key is hit, it will go through the tooltip references array and close them all.